# How can I find Vs?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Schematic]

I thought about using KVL to calculate the resistor voltages... but I don't know how the arrow symbol and `Vo` interferes with the rest of the circuit.

Comment: The choice of KCL or KVL is up to you but one choice might be better than the other, though I'd probably use KCL if I had to choose.

Comment: This arrow indicates the current direction for a 3mA current source. Do you know the current source?

Comment: Or replace Vs and the 3k resistors with their Thevenin equivalent- you can pretty much do the whole thing in your head that way.  Or use superposition.

Comment: You need to add reference designators. In this case you should label your resistors R1 and R2. Then write some equations and show us your attempted analysis.

Comment: A current source is a circuit element that maintains a prescribed (set) current (3mA) regardless of the voltage across its terminals. Do you know source transformation? You can "change"  Vs and the first 3k resistor into the current source.

Comment: What is the voltage across the resistor parallel with the current source? And the current through this resistor?

Comment: @G36 I suppose the voltage is 6 volts because of the current source and 2mA current (assuming the voltage across the resistor is the same because of being parallel to the current source)

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, if only 2mA from the current source enters 3k the rest of the current (1mA) must flow into another 3k (R1) resistor.  So the voltage drop across this R1 resistor is?  And VS is?

Comment: @G36 Is both 3V?

Comment: yep, they are.  As you can see you can solve this problem.  Good job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vo indicates that the voltage across the current source is 6V. The arrow shows that there's a 3mA current flowing upward (note that Vo is open-circuit so no current flows through that branch). If you don't know what a current source is then do read a book, a paper, etc.

I think you've made no more progress since your last question, given the detailed answers you received. You can't expect to learn things on your own. Go to your classes and learn from your teacher, or your friends, if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

We are not here to do your homework for you.

The arrow thingy is a *current source*.  Look it up.  Understand it.

There are many ways to analyze this circuit.  If you don't know where to begin, then you probably didn't pay attention in class and need to read the text carefully.  We are not a substitute for doing your coursework properly.

Once you figure out a plan of attack and show some effort, we may be able to help if you get stuck somewhere specific.

Comment: The problem with the "class" is i dont go to classes im learning by myself, but thanks anyway! And i only didnt know the english name to the current source, i've looked it up and all of that and besides that ive tried lots of stuff, its just to dumb to post it here when it doesnt make sense.